# How set div´s width and height dynamically depending on the conent

Tags: html, css

I want to set the `.editBokningar` div to dynamically change as I add content. Right now it takes up almost the whole screen because of the `100%`. How can I achive this the best way? The Snippet height is not accurate here. In the snippet  the height stays close to the conent.

```css
    .EditBoking {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
        background-color: #E1E777;
        border-radius: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

    .title {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FF3333;
    }

    .listOneRow {
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
        ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

```html
       <div class="EditBoking">
                <div class="title">
                    Din nuvarande bokning
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul class="listOneRow">
                        <li>
                            <span>Startdatum: 2017-12-12</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span>Slutdatum: 2017-12-12</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span>Program: some program</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span>Miljö: Arrendator</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make your element inline-block and remove height/width property:

```css
.EditBoking {
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
  background-color: #E1E777;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FF3333;
}

.listOneRow {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="EditBoking">
  <div class="title">
    Din nuvarande bokning
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul class="listOneRow">
      <li>
        <span>Startdatum: 2017-12-12</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Slutdatum: 2017-12-12</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Program: some program</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Miljö: Arrendator</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="EditBoking">
  <div class="title">
    Din nuvarande bokning
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul class="listOneRow">
      <li>
        <span>Startdatum: 2017-12-12</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Slutdatum: 2017-12-12</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="EditBoking">
  <div class="title">
    Din nuvarande bokning
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul class="listOneRow">
      <li>
        <span>Startdatum: 2017-12-12</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Slutdatum: 2017-12-12</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="listOneRow">
      <li>
        <span>Startdatum: 2017-12-12</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Slutdatum: 2017-12-12</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="listOneRow">
      <li>
        <span>Startdatum: 2017-12-12</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Slutdatum: 2017-12-12</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! for your help

Answer (score 2):

As EditBoking is div which is a block element, it is not necessary to define width: 100% as it will by default take up the whole space

But for your question,

just remove

```
height: 100%;
```

from the code.

Comment: yes. the height is ok now, what should I do about the width?

Comment: `.listOneRow {display: inline-block}` is also unnecessary.

Comment: you are right, it was a left over from a diffrent style

Answer (score 1):

use display inline-block as below

```
.EditBoking{
 display: inline-block;
 height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! for your help